# Vue.js - Is it possible to use Javascript Dynamic Imports to load components from another server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

## Context

I have to create a Vue.js application as the UI of my REST API Back-end.
It will be displayed for every client.

This application displays a list of items to be handled (with a small workflow: open, in progress, done).

Some of my clients request a specific and different view for this list: they want, for instance, that the list is displayed in another layout, or with extra data from their internal applications.

## My idea

So, I have to create specific Vue.js components for these clients, but I don't want to "pollute" my main application code base with all the components for these clients.
I want that these views are handled in a specifically dedicated code base.

I was wondering if I could use Dynamic imports / Async components ([Article on optimization with Dynamic imports](https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-1-introduction-to-performance-optimization-and-lazy-29e4ff101019) and [Official Vue.js doc for Dynamic imports](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)) to load these components, based on the client that uses the application.
These components would be loaded from ***another server***, not the server that serves the main Vue.js application.

---

The actual way of dynamically loading a component is:

```
'my-component': () => import('./my-async-component')
```

Would it be possible to do something like:

```
'my-component': () => import('http://myspecificclient.mydomain.com/my-async-component')
```

---

I understand that dynamic loading is related in particular with Webpack and that it could be an issue here, but I'm not skilled enough in Webpack to know if what I would like to do is relevant.

Comment: Looks like it is : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules `import {shout} from 'https://simple.example/modules/lib.mjs';`

Comment: It is interesting, I understand you can load javascript functions and objects from another server.
Although in my case, I want to go a bit further: I want to load Vue.js components (defined in ".vue" files). These files are usually handled by Webpack to convert them into packages and chunks.

Would it be possible to load directly a Vue.js component, that may, itself, have dependency on subcomponent on the specific server?

Comment: Have you tried loading a vue file that way using the `async component` ? Try fetching the file from a local web server (with http-server if you want to test quickly)

Comment: I would need some guidance to do that... the vue components are compiled by webpack into chunks, and I don't know what I am supposed to target in my url ( import('????')  )

It would be easier if it was javascript files ".js" that can be directly accessed on a web server, but it is not the case :-/

Comment: Using this syntax : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State, what happens if you use a full http URL instead of a relative path ? You may have to use a function instead of directly using the import statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This recent article (7 April 2019), by Markus Oberlehner, presents a way to do this:

https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/?utm_source=Vue.js+Developers&utm_campaign=a23e0b1135-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2019_04_02_10_08_COPY_01&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_ae2f1465e2-a23e0b1135-209131157

An excerpt:

```
// This does not work.
const MyComponent = () => import('https://distribution.server/MyComponent.js');
```

> Ideally, we could do it the way you see above. But this does not work because neither webpack nor the native implementation of import() can deal with external resources.
>
> In the following example code snippet you can see our own implementation of import() which does work with external resources.

```
// src/utils/external-component.js
export default function externalComponent(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const name = url.split('/').reverse()[0].match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(window[name]);
    });
    script.addEventListener('error', () => {
      reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
    });
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

```
import externalComponent from '../utils/external-component';

const MyComponent = () => externalComponent('http://localhost:8200/MyComponent/MyComponent.c9c0abb8e999d0e5654e.umd.min.js');

export default {
  name: 'MyOtherComponent',
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to use ajax...

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open('GET', '[Your url here]', true)
```

But I'm not really sure since you said you wanted to import it from another server