# Lazy import vue

Tags: vue.js

How i can lazy import externial library

For example i have pdfvuer:

```
import {createLoadingTask} from 'pdfvuer'
```

But i use it after event (click) only.

```
 createLoadingTask({
   data: atob(
    data.data)
      }).then(function (pdfDoc_) { ...
 }
})
```

if i do it :

```
 const FontTab = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import("pdfvuer")
    )
```

or

```
 let createLoadingTask = ()=> import("pdfvuer");
```

it doesn't work.
Can i import this libary lazy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - Is it possible to use Javascript Dynamic Imports to load components from another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763605/vue-js-is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-dynamic-imports-to-load-components-fro)

Comment: Seems like the `pdfvuer` has some issues with internal imports from `pdfjs-dist` maybe you should create an issue on [their github](https://github.com/arkokoley/pdfvuer/issues).